# Scala: Unit/Integration testing the parallel processing for the for-comprehension

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, playframework-2.0, for-comprehension

I have a Play project which uses for-comprehension to complete the tasks in parallel. Let's say we are given with the code below. I want to test that function firstF and secondF is in fact happening in parallel. What would be the best way to test this? I thought of asserting that the start and end time overlaps, but there could be a better way to test this.

```
   def async = Action.async {     
    val firstF = future{
      val s = "start: " + new java.util.Date().toString() + " :: "
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      val e = "end: " + new java.util.Date().toString()
      "First function: " + s + e + "\n\n"
    }

    val secondF = future{
      val s = "start: " + new java.util.Date().toString() + " :: "
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      val e = "end: " + new java.util.Date().toString()
      "Second function: " + s + e + "\n\n"
    }

    val result = for {
      fContent <- firstF
      sContent <- secondF
    } yield fContent + sContent

    result map {
      x => Ok( x )
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

To test the running time of some execution, the standard way is to use the ScalaMeter framework for performance regression testing.

```
val gen = Gen.range("times")(1000, 2000, 500)
performance of "Futures" in {
  using(gen) in { time =>
    val f: Future[Unit] = runningFor(time) // returns some future that takes time milliseconds to execute
    Await.ready(f)
  }
}
```

See a complete [Getting Started example here](http://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.5/simplemicrobenchmark/index.html).

Manual method:

You can print the name of the current thread using `Thread.currentThread.getName`. In the standard `ExecutionContext` implementation, this will print the names of the fork/join worker threads. If the names are different for the two future computations, that is a good indication that they are executing in parallel.

Otherwise, you can try timing the start and the end of the futures using `System.currentTimeMillis`, and comparing if the two intervals overlap.

Finally, in your example, each future takes a long amount of time. If the program completes in 1 second, they are obviously executing in parallel. If the program completes in 2 seconds, the two futures are executed serially, because the `ExecutionContext` is using only one thread.

Note that, `Thread.sleep` is a long-running blocking operation, which blocks the worker thread. Generally, use the `blocking` directive around blocking operations, to allow resizing the worker thread pool when necessary:

```
Future { // note: lowercase `future` has been deprecated, use uppercase
  blocking {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think execution context is using a single thread; could you prove otherwise? I printed the timestamp specifically to prove this point. Both timestamps are identical it starts and end at the exactly same time in 1 seconds. I would assume these two are happening at the same time.

Comment: The standard execution context implementation uses a fork/join pool initialized with the number of threads equal to the number of processors on the machine. If by some chance your computer has a single core, then your execution context will have a single thread by default: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L63

Comment: Of course, if a fork/join pool detects that some worker thread is blocked, it can temporarily add additional worker threads to prevent starvation. The `blocking` construct signals potential blocked computations to the fork/join pool.

Comment: I am aware of blocking{ }. My question is how to unit test in standard manner. Your suggestion seems very manual.

Comment: You can execute a performance regression test using [ScalaMeter](http://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.5/simplemicrobenchmark/index.html). I've edited to show the gist of the ScalaMeter unit test.